# Exoplayer should play video with lowest video quality

Tags: android, android-studio, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I would like to play my video at the lowest resolution(256x144).
I have configured the `DefaultTrackSelector` by setting two parameters:

1.`setMaxVideoSize(width, height)` to limit the resolution to your parameters.
2.`setForceHighestSupportedBitrate(true)` to force-select the highest bitrate that is still within size constraints.

**Full Code**

```
DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(requireContext());
            trackSelector.setParameters(trackSelector
                    .buildUponParameters()
                    .setMaxVideoSize(256, 144)
                    .setForceHighestSupportedBitrate(true));
            player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(requireContext())
                    .setTrackSelector(trackSelector)
                    .build();
            player.setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(videoUri));
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
player.prepare();
playerView.setPlayer(player);
```

But still, it is playing video with different video resolutions.
Someone, please help me to fix this issue.

**Log**

```
3314-13314/com.example D/EventLogger: downstreamFormat [eventTime=0.60, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, id=1, mimeType=video/avc, codecs=avc1.640028, res=1920x1080, fps=30.0]
2021-06-26 16:52:44.683 13314-13314/com.example D/EventLogger: videoInputFormat [eventTime=0.61, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, id=1, mimeType=video/avc, codecs=avc1.640028, res=1920x1080, fps=30.0]
2021-06-26 16:52:45.208 13314-13314/com.example D/EventLogger: downstreamFormat [eventTime=1.22, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, id=1, mimeType=video/avc, codecs=avc1.42C01E, res=480x270, fps=29.999668]
2021-06-26 16:52:45.278 13314-13314/com.example D/EventLogger: videoInputFormat [eventTime=1.27, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, id=1, mimeType=video/avc, codecs=avc1.42C01E, res=480x270, fps=29.999668]
2021-06-26 16:52:45.317 13314-13314/com.example D/EventLogger: downstreamFormat [eventTime=1.42, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, id=1, mimeType=video/avc, codecs=avc1.4D401F, res=720x720, fps=29.999668]
2021-06-26 16:52:45.590 13314-13314/com.example D/EventLogger: videoInputFormat [eventTime=1.69, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, id=1, mimeType=video/avc, codecs=avc1.4D401F, res=720x720, fps=29.999668]
2021-06-26 16:52:54.257 13314-13314/com.example D/EventLogger: downstreamFormat [eventTime=0.21, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, id=1, mimeType=video/avc, codecs=avc1.64001F, res=960x540, fps=29.999342]
2021-06-26 16:52:54.666 13314-13314/com.example D/EventLogger: videoInputFormat [eventTime=0.62, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, id=1, mimeType=video/avc, codecs=avc1.64001F, res=960x540, fps=29.999342]
2021-06-26 16:52:56.331 13314-13314/com.example D/EventLogger: downstreamFormat [eventTime=0.60, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, id=1, mimeType=video/avc, codecs=avc1.64001F, res=608x1080, fps=30.0]
2021-06-26 16:52:56.413 13314-13314/com.example D/EventLogger: videoInputFormat [eventTime=0.69, mediaPos=0.00, window=0, period=0, id=1, mimeType=video/avc, codecs=avc1.64001F, res=608x1080, fps=30.0]
```

**Reference Link**

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/6756

[Set max bitrate on ExoPlayer](https://takusemba.medium.com/set-max-bitrate-on-exoplayer-e9cd4cc77445)

Comment: Did you get ANY SOLUTION ?

Comment: Sorry @madhu527 still i did not get any solution. If you get solution please post here as answer. It will help many peoples.

Comment: Sure i will do that

Comment: Are you using a format (e.g. DASH) with multiple tracks?
The track selector will never eliminate all tracks.
(i.e. you'll always have at least one track left to play in the end)

Answer (score 0):

First we need to check available tracks in video and during ilteration we need to store Formats & Bitrate in ArrayList.

```
  if(formatList!=null){formatList.clear();}
        if(bitrateList!=null){bitrateList.clear();}
        final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
                .excludeFieldsWithModifiers(TRANSIENT) // STATIC|TRANSIENT in the default configuration
                .create();
        if (trackSelector.getCurrentMappedTrackInfo() != null) {
            Log.d("TAG", "log tracks clicked");
            MappingTrackSelector.MappedTrackInfo mappedTrackInfo = trackSelector.getCurrentMappedTrackInfo();
            DefaultTrackSelector.Parameters parameters = trackSelector.getParameters();

            for (int rendererIndex = 0; rendererIndex < mappedTrackInfo.getRendererCount(); rendererIndex++) {
                if (TrackSelectionDialog.showTabForRenderer(mappedTrackInfo, rendererIndex)) {
                    int trackType = mappedTrackInfo.getRendererType(rendererIndex);
                    TrackGroupArray trackGroupArray = mappedTrackInfo.getTrackGroups(rendererIndex);
                    Boolean isRendererDisabled = parameters.getRendererDisabled(rendererIndex);
                    DefaultTrackSelector.SelectionOverride selectionOverride = parameters.getSelectionOverride(rendererIndex, trackGroupArray);

                    Log.d("TAG", "------------------------------------------------------Track item " + rendererIndex + "------------------------------------------------------");
                    Log.d("TAG", "track type: ");
                    Log.d("TAG", "track group array: " + gson.toJson(trackGroupArray));
                    for (int groupIndex = 0; groupIndex < trackGroupArray.length; groupIndex++) {
                        for (int trackIndex = 0; trackIndex < trackGroupArray.get(groupIndex).length; trackIndex++) {
                            TrackNameProvider trackNameProvider = new DefaultTrackNameProvider(getResources());
                            String trackName = trackNameProvider.getTrackName(trackGroupArray.get(groupIndex).getFormat(trackIndex));
                            String[] widthxheight = trackName.split(",");
                            //  Log.d("TAG", "wid" + widthxheight[0]);
                            String[] height = widthxheight[0].split("×");
                            //  Log.d("TAG", "hei" + height[0]);
                            Boolean isTrackSupported = mappedTrackInfo.getTrackSupport(rendererIndex, groupIndex, trackIndex) == RendererCapabilities.FORMAT_HANDLED;
                            Log.d("TAG", "track item " + groupIndex + ": trackName: " + trackName + ", isTrackSupported: " + isTrackSupported);
                            if(rendererIndex == 0)
                            {
                                formatList.add(height[1] + "p");
                                bitrateList.add(Double.parseDouble(widthxheight[1].replace("Mbps","").trim()));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d("TAG", "bitrate" + bitrateList);
                    Log.d("TAG", "isRendererDisabled: " + isRendererDisabled);
                    Log.d("TAG", "selectionOverride: " +  gson.toJson(selectionOverride));
                }
            }
        }
```

Now Using bitrate Arraylist for example suppose we have: [0.4,0.8,2.6,4.5]
we can setMaxVideoBitrate accordingly.
you can refer to this link  https://gadgetspidy.com/how-to-add-popup-menu-inside-transparent-dialog-in-android-studio/

```
DefaultTrackSelector.ParametersBuilder builder = new DefaultTrackSelector.ParametersBuilder(this);
        builder.setMaxVideoBitrate((int) Math.round(bitrate));
        //40000000
        //4.5  * 1000000
        //2.6  * 1000000
        //0.8  * 1000000
        //0.4  * 1000000
        trackSelectorParameters = builder.build();
        trackSelector.setParameters(trackSelectorParameters);
```